# What causes v.net connect "Failed to find intersection segment" and how to fix it?

Tags: grass-gis, network

In GRASS 7, when running v.net connect, I get the `ERROR: Failed to find intersection segment` and no output is generated. The only mention of this error Google found is in the source of [connect.c](https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass/branches/releasebranch_7_0/vector/v.net/connect.c)

What can cause this error and how can I fix my input data so that I can build a network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A check of the input line topology using

```
v.build -e map=lines@agraser
```

revealed

```
WARNING: Number of lines of length zero: 140
```

After removing those with v.clean "remove lines/boundaries of zero length", network creation succeeded.